# What does "column stacked version of an image" mean?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

Recently I've been reading an article about image processing, and [it states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k4gd.png) as follows:

> Let **Y** be an image of size *N*<sub>1</sub>×*N*<sub>2</sub>, where *N*<sub>1</sub>*N*<sub>2</sub> = *N*, and let **Z** be a corrupted version of **Y**, which may be noisy. Also, let **z** and **y** be the column stacked versions of **Z** and **Y**, respectively.

Can anyone please explain what would be conceptually and mathematically the *column stacked version* of a given image??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *column stacked version* of a matrix means that it's a column vector, which is created by concatenating the columns of this matrix one by one. In MATLAB this can be simply achieved by the [`colon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator:

```
Y_stacked = Y(:); %// Stacked (or "columnized") Y
Z_stacked = Z(:); %// Stacked (or "columnized") Z
```

Since the stacked array contains the same number of elements as the original matrix, its length should be *N* = *N*<sub>1</sub>*N*<sub>2</sub>, where *N*<sub>1</sub>×*N*<sub>2</sub> are the dimensions of the original matrix.

This is equivalent to the [`vec`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) transformation in mathematics.

Comment: Whether the paper uses column major or row major stacking could be an issue? Probably not but still might be something to consider as well.

Comment: But it says "column stacked", not "row stacked", so it must be column-major, no?